# How can I stop multi-type when using mouse collision in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

My code have a problem multi-click when using collision with `mouse.get_pos()` and `mouse.get_pressed()`. When I click one time, sometime it's click 1 - 2 time, I cant find how to solve this one the internet. How can I fix that?

Help me with this problem please.